# Установление изначального значения свойству C#

Tags: c#, классы, инициализация

Здравствуйте. Сражу скажу что я только начинаю постигать азы, так что прошу понятного для начинающего изложения ответа. Есть класс `configuration`, в нем два свойства `Name`, `Money`. Мне необходимо задать им начальное значение, например чтобы `Money` был равен 100, есть ли способ это реализовать или нет? (Чтобы при создании объекта этого класса ему сразу было присвоено это значение) Заранее благодарю каждого обратившего внимание.

```
using System;
namespace COOKING_GAME
{
    public class configuration
    {
    string Name { get; set; }
    int Money { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: в самом классе объявить переменную , либо создать отдельный класс и вызывать его при необходимости в программе

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В C# 6 вы можете написать в определении класса

```
public class configuration
{
    string Name { get; set; } = "Bob";
    int Money { get; set; } = 190;
}
```

Иначе, если объявить члены класса с модификатором `public`, то при создании объекта вы можете написать

```
configuration c = new configuration { Name = "Bob", Money = 100 };
```

И, наконец, вы можете объявить конструктор по умолчанию, в котором будете инициализировать данные члены класса.

Answer (score 7):

Да, инициализировать свойства всегда можно в конструкторе:

```
public class configuration
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    int Money { get; set; }
    public configuration(){
        Money = 100;
    }
}
```

Кроме того, в новых версиях, добавили инициализацию при объявлении

```
public class configuration
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    int Money { get; set; } = 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Любой класс поддерживает создание экземпляра себя при помощи конструктора:

```
class Configuration()
{
    // Без модификаторов доступа эти поля по умолчанию Private
    string name;
    int money;

    //Конструктор без параметров (здесь можно задать значение по умолчанию)
    public Configuration()
    {
        name = "StandartName";
        money = 1000;
    }

    // Конструктор с параметрами (создание экземпляра с указанными значениями)
    public Configuration(string _name, int _money)
    {
        name = _name;
        money = _money;
    }

    // Также в класс можно добавить свойства доступа к полям
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
        }
    }
    public string Money
    {
        get
        {
            return money;
        }
        set
        {
            money = value;
        }
    }
}
```

теперь для создания экземпляра класса вы можете воспользоваться конструкциями:

```
// Для вызова конструктора без параметров (по умолчанию)
Configuration conf = new Configuration();

// Для вызова конструктора с параметрами (name = Alex, money = 1500)
Configuration conf1 = new Configuration("Alex",1500);

// Также для доступа к полям экземпляра класса можно использовать свойства
Console.WriteLine(conf1.Name);
Console.WriteLine(conf1.Money);

conf1.Money = 2015;

Console.WriteLine(conf1.Money);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну и еще один вариант с полем:

```
public class configuration
{
    public string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; } }
    private string _name = "Bob";

    public int Money { get { return _money; } set { _money = value; } }
    private int _money = 190;
}
```